# What is the Make in Linux? Is it the same idea as of "Build" in Eclipse?

Tags: build, makefile, difference

I am kinda confuse between these two concepts. Are they related? What I understand is we need to "Build" codes in our project to generate executable program. What about "Make"? What is it for?

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/umake.htm

Comment: You are correct: the 'build' step is exactly what `make` is for.

Answer (score 3):

In concept, executing `make` is generally similar to running a build in Eclipse or some other IDE. The `make` utility is a system for determining, for a given collection of source files, what code needs to be compiled or recompiled to get a working executable.

The way it works is by use of a `makefile`, which specifies the relationships between the source files and contains the commands used to build each file. When you run `make` with the applicable arguments in the command line, it reads the make file for your project and compiles anything that needs to be recompiled.

If you're interested in finding out more, I'd suggest reading [the manual page for make](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make), or looking for other resources that give an introduction to writing a makefile if the manual is too dense for your tastes.

Answer (score 2):

Compling software (converting from source code to machine instructions) is generally called building it.  There are many tools to do so.  Some of them are IDEs (Visual Studio, Eclipse, RSA).  Some of them are tools such as Ant, Maven, and make (on unix).  Generally speaking these tools convert source to something the processor or a runtime can process.

Comment: To be more specific: IDEs *include* a build tool. For instance, Visual Studio started out using `make`; it now uses `MSBuild`. Eclipse tends to use `ant` and/or `maven`.